# compare the timestamp with a specific date in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe: (The name of dataframe is: `df`)

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+----+-----+--------------------+-------------------+------+------+------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------+
|   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2| count|rank|   xi|                  pi|                  r|   ip5|   ip4|   ip3|  ip2|            variance|             entropy|    pre_chi_square|  total_chi_square|attack|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+----+-----+--------------------+-------------------+------+------+------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------+
|07:19:00.005763|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.1|509286|   1|92055|1.963533260289896E-6|0.18075305427598637|111891|115199|190028|92055|1.317855896447428...|2.580232918985576E-5|3.7131630265751565|14.852652106300626|     1|
|07:19:00.005788|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.1|509286|   2|92055|3.927066520579792E-6|0.18075305427598637|111891|115199|190028|92055|6.498626409377348E-6|4.888262329310028E-5|18.310392943472664|14.852652106300626|     1|
|07:19:00.005807|   10.0.0.2|     10.0.0.1|509286|   3|92055|5.890599780869688E-6|0.18075305427598637|111891|115199|190028|92055|1.560646344288706E-5|7.093550226267817E-5|  43.9724428049685|14.852652106300626|     1|
```

I need to put the zero value for `attack` field if, both the time stamp is bigger than **"07:19:00.005788"** and the `sender_ip_1` is equal to **10.0.0.3**.

However, I don't know how to deal with timestamp comparison with a specific datae in a condition in scala. Here is my code:

```
val df_attack = df
  .withColumn("attack",
    when($"sender_ip_1" === "10.0.0.3"
      and ($"time_stamp_0").cast(TimestampType) > "07:19:00.005788", 0)
      .otherwise(1))
```

Can any body helps me?

Comment: completely unrelated: http://wiki.c2.com/?BadVariableNames

Comment: @philantrovert: Thanks, I changed it.

Comment: I didn't mean you should change it. I posted it as light humour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple lexicographic comparison also works here for column `time_stamp_0` as well.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val final_add_count_rank_xi_pi_r_attack = Dataframe_add_rank_count_xi_pi_final_chi_square
  .withColumn("attack",
    when($"sender_ip_1" === "10.0.0.3"
      && $"time_stamp_0" > "07:19:00.005788", 0)
      .otherwise(1))
```